# Html css image problems windows IE FF GChrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a website I have just built. Everything looks reasonable in Mac browsers, but in windows browsers such as IE there seems to be some rendering problems in terms of very thin sketchy white lines in between where the main header image butts joins the surrounding background image, and also between the background image and the surrounding background colour. The images were created in photoshop. I'm probably not explaining it very well, but please take a look at the site. The link is below. Thankyou

http://www.eve-tattoo.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are img artifacts. Here's the fixed jpg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MICbj.jpg

Comment: img artifacts? how and why do they appear and how can I fix them? They are not visible on my mac. Thankyou very much for your reply.

Comment: well, there were just dark-grey lines. if they do/don't appear depends heavily on your display parameters and/or image settings (e.g. they won't be visible if brightness/contrast are set to low).

Comment: How can I prevent them in the future?